# How to have break in flex div so that overflowing items can come in next line is css?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui

1. I use `material-ui` popper to show a list of avatars.
2. I want to show avatars horizontally in the popper.

```
<Popper style={{ display: 'flex', maxWidth: '200px',  }}>
  <div style={{ marginRight: '20px' }}><Avatar /></div>
  <div style={{ marginRight: '20px' }}><Avatar /></div>
</Popper>
```

3. It's overflowing from the popper, but I want them to come to next line.
4. I need a maxWidth. because I don't want popper to grow longer.
5. Looking like this right now:

[image]

Comment: try adding overflow: hidden; to the container div

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `flex-wrap: wrap` (`flexWrap: 'wrap'`) to the code, so It will go to the next line everytime the items occupy the full width.

```
<Popper style={{ display: 'flex', maxWidth: '200px', flexWrap: 'wrap' }}>
  <div style={{ marginRight: '20px' }}><Avatar /></div>
  <div style={{ marginRight: '20px' }}><Avatar /></div>
</Popper>
```

Comment: Thanks! Worked well.

Answer (score 1):

Use flexWrap:'wrap' in container View